# HM-11 BLE Battery Service

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, hm-10

How can I include battery information in the IBeacon advertisement packet of HM-11 BLE module. I have tried deploying the Ibeacon mode on HM-10 modules, but on testing the transmitted packets using BLE Android app the battery service seems to be missing.Is there any AT Command to include the battery level.Also are there some user customizable bits in the HM-11 ibeacon advertisement packet?